# react-scripts issues with npm run build

Tags: node.js, reactjs, build, react-scripts

We are facing these errors on running the command `npm run build` (to build the frontend of the project) on production setup (errors reported by DevOps team, not sure if they tried this after removing dependency react-scripts. Package.json copied below) -

```
> mvc-panel@0.1.0 build /usr/local/mvc/releases/2017-10-23-17:00/mvc_build/panel/mvc-panel
> react-scripts build

sh: react-scripts: command not found

npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v7.2.1/bin/node" "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v7.2.1/bin/npm" "run" "build"
npm ERR! node v7.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! mvc-panel@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the mvc-panel@0.1.0 build script 'react-scripts build'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the mvc-panel package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     react-scripts build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs mvc-panel
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls mvc-panel
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /usr/local/mvc/releases/2017-10-23-17:00/mvc_build/panel/mvc-panel/npm-debug.log
```

and after installing react-scripts , we are facing these errors

```
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v7.2.1/bin/react-scripts -> /root/.nvm/versions/node/v7.2.1/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js

> uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall /root/.nvm/versions/node/v7.2.1/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
> node lib/post_install.js

module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v7.2.1/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/lib/post_install.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:427:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:151:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:542:3
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v7.2.1/lib
└── (empty)

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.2 (node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v7.2.1/bin/node" "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v7.2.1/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "react-scripts"
npm ERR! node v7.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall: `node lib/post_install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall script 'node lib/post_install.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the uglifyjs-webpack-plugin package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node lib/post_install.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /usr/local/mvc/releases/2017-10-23-17:00/mvc_build/panel/mvc-panel/node_modules/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
```

**Following is the package.json file -**

```
{
  "name": "mvc-panel",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "material-ui": "^0.18.3",
    "qs": "^6.4.0",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-alert": "^2.1.2",
    "react-bootstrap-table": "^3.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-loader": "^2.4.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "serve": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.15",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Previously, we had got the following while trying to build on our staging server -

```
> mvc-panel@0.1.0 build D:\Sandeepan\Payu MVC\backend codebase\MVC2.0\panel\mvc-
panel
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './../common/panelConfig.js' in 'D:\Sande
epan\Payu MVC\backend codebase\MVC2.0\panel\mvc-panel\src\components'


npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
npm ERR! node v6.11.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! mvc-panel@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mvc-panel@0.1.0 build script 'react-scripts build'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the mvc-panel package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     react-scripts build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs mvc-panel
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls mvc-panel
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\Sandeepan\Payu MVC\backend codebase\MVC2.0\panel\mvc-panel\npm-d
ebug.log
```

It seems they had been getting away with this by doing a `rm -rf reacts-scripts` but I could not verify the same. I tried by removing the entire `node_modules` directory and running the following commands -

```
npm install 
npm install -g serve 
npm run build
```

But still getting the same error.

I looked for './../common/panelConfig.js' in the codebase and found many files in components directory including files like this -

```
var panelConfig = require('./../common/panelConfig.js');
```

If I change this to (just hit and trial) -

```
var panelConfig = require(__dirname+'/../common/panelConfig.js');
```

I still get the following error on build -

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'D:\Sandeepan\Payu MVC\backend codebase\M
VC2.0\panel\mvc-panel\src\components/../common/panelConfig.js' in 'D:\Sandeepan\
Payu MVC\backend codebase\MVC2.0\panel\mvc-panel\src\components'
```

Could someone give some pointers please.

Comment: Hey Sandeepan, did you guys managed to figure this out? On my local win machine, npm install works. When porting to nix env, npm install fails at post_install.js for uglify-webpack-plugin@0.4.6. I managed to workaround it by copying the uglifyjs node module from my local env to the nix server and running npm install again. I'm looking for a more perm solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First of all there are two different problems here, it is better to separate them out.

For your first question, `Error: Cannot find module` means the package is missing or its not properly installed. Most of the cases it would get solved once you remove your `node_modules` and do a fresh install.

Regarding this error `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/lib/post_install.js`, I see that the `react-scripts` package is fixed to `1.0.7` version. I tried it out with latest version `1.0.14` and it worked just fine for me. Update your package.json with a `^` before the version to auto install the latest releases

```
"react-scripts": "^1.0.7"
```

Another approach, a temporary solution I once got it fixed by installing the beta version of that package. you can try it out with the following command.

```
npm i -D uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@beta
```

Coming to your second problem,

The slash `'/'` varies with the operating system you use, for example Windows uses backward slash `'\'` whereas the rest of the OS' follows forward slash `'/'` and that causes your reference error.

`var panelConfig = require('./../common/panelConfig.js');` this seems fine. Are you sure that the `panelConfig.js` file exist in the mentioned path? If not kindly pass the appropriate path to `require`. Hope this will fix your reference issue.